# Time Series Forecast using Arima in R

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

I am trying to forecast student behaviour by year. It isn't working, maybe because my data is too small. I'm using Arima; however, the trend line keeps showing a straight line which I'm not sure is right. Might be this because ARIMA shows ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean.

[image: Image Data]

Year - General
Students - Numeric

How can I forecast a student's behaviour by year?

Comment: Be good to see what code you have tried.
It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: `df <- structure(list(Year = structure(c(9131, 9496, 9862), class = "Date"), 
                     Student1 = c(3, 1, 3), Student2 = c(2, 2, 2), Student3 = c(2, 
`  - Your image as code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Small data set, but this is one way to go about it. Modelling each student separately (with student as a key), and using the tidyverts approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)
library(fable)
```

Data set

```
df <- structure(list(Year = structure(c(1995, 1996, 1997), class = "numeric"), 
                     Student1 = c(3, 1, 3), Student2 = c(2, 2, 2), Student3 = c(2, 
                                                                                3, 3), Student4 = c(2, 3, 2), Student5 = c(3, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                3L), class = "data. Frame")
```

Tidy data

```
df <- df |> pivot_longer(names_to = "Student", cols = starts_with("Student")) |>
  as_tsibble(index = Year, key = Student)
```

Visualise

```
df |> autoplot()

df |>
  filter(Student == "Student1") |>
  gg_tsdisplay(value, plot_type = 'partial')
```

Fit ARIMA

```
Stu_fit <- df |>
  model(search = ARIMA(value, stepwise = FALSE))
```

Check fit

```
glance(Stu_fit)
Stu_fit$search

Stu_fit |>
  filter(Student == "Student1") |>
  gg_tsresiduals()
```

Forecast

```
Stu_fit |>
  forecast(h = 5) |>
  filter(.model == 'search') |>
  autoplot()
```

Hope this is helps! :-)